# Dc Composite Chart

Tags: dc.js

I have a data like this

Sl.No,Sex,Age_band,TYPE of Mesh,Type of Surgery
16,M,0-25,PHS,UL Inguinal
20,M,0-25,PHS,UL Inguinal
90,M,0-25,UHSL,UL Inguinal
95,M,0-25,UHSL,UL Inguinal
117,M,0-25,UHSL,UL Inguinal
119,M,0-25,UHSL,UL Inguinal
32,M,0-25,Ultrapro,Incisional
14,M,26-35,PHS,UL Inguinal
18,M,26-35,PHS,UL Inguinal

I am trying to plot a composite chart
and my code is

```
var mFilteredData = crossfilter(mData);
        var mDimension = mFilteredData.dimension(dc.pluck("Age_band"));
        var mGroup = mDimension.group().reduceCount(dc.pluck("TYPE of Mesh"));
        var mGroup1 = mDimension.group().reduceCount(dc.pluck("Type of Surgery"));


        var chart = dc.compositeChart(".chart");
        chart
        .width(400)
        .height(300)
        .yAxisLabel("User Count")
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .dimension(mDimension)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .compose([
            dc.barChart(chart)
            .centerBar(true)
            .gap(100)
            .colors('red')
            .group(mGroup)
            ,
            dc.barChart(chart)
            .centerBar(true)
            .gap(100)
            .colors('blue')
            .group(mGroup1)])
        .brushOn(false)
        .render();
```

But I am getting this errror

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'all' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue. After some digging around in the dc source code I saw that if you have an ordinal x scale, the chart calls it's groups all() function (not completely sure why, but it seems to be using the data for the x axis domain). By adding a group to your composite chart you will solve this issue. Like so:

```
  dc.compositeChart(".chart")
    .width(400)
    .height(300)
    .yAxisLabel("User Count")
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .dimension(mDimension)
    .group(mGroup)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```